# What transforms does FreeType do to a glyph?

Tags: truetype, freetype, freetype2

I find that freetype2 doesn't handle subglyphs' placements correctly (or I'm perhaps using it wrong). For example, when I try to render the 'Ã', the A with the tilde on top of it, I get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRuzp.png Ignore the little tails and red text everywhere; the point is that the tilde is intersecting with the A.

When I specify the FT_LOAD_NO_RECURSE flag, and then add the two subglyphs on my own (using the offsets from arg1 and arg2 from FT_Get_SubGlyph_Info), it's correct: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw4yj.png

It's a similar story with almost every other compound character.

Perhaps relevant: the exact calls I'm using are:

```
FT_Library library = { };
FT_Init_FreeType(&library);
...
FT_Face face = { };
FT_New_Face(library, "arial.ttf", 0, &face);
...
FT_Set_Char_Size(face, 10, 10, 72, 72);
...
FT_Load_Glyph(face, glyphIndex, FT_LOAD_NO_BITMAP);
```

So, first question: am I somehow using freetype2 wrong?

If it is indeed a bug in freetype2, and I have to proceed with FT_LOAD_NO_RECURSE, the problem I have is that FT_LOAD_NO_RECURSE implies FT_LOAD_NO_SCALE and FT_LOAD_IGNORE_TRANSFORM. The effect is that my resulting characters have very weird coordinates. For example, the slash character, '/', used to have these four points:

- top: 28,46
- right: 34,43
- left: 4,1
- bottom: 10,-2

but now that there's no scaling or transforming, I get these points:

- top: 901,1474
- right: 1087,1376
- bottom: 328,-74
- left: 142,24

The main question: How do I get back to the first set of coordinates? What do I add/multiply?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was the answer:

```
FT_Load_Glyph(face, glyphIndex, FT_LOAD_NO_BITMAP);
float scaleX = face->size->metrics.x_scale / 65536.0;
float scaleY = face->size->metrics.y_scale / 65536.0;

for each point:
    point = vec2(round(point.point.x * scaleX), round(point.point.y * scaleY));
```

face->size->metrics has how much we're supposed to scale it to get from grid units to font units. Then, we gotta round at the end. This must be what happens when FT_LOAD_NO_SCALE isn't set.